# PostgreSQL Transformation Process Code

Tags: postgresql, relational-algebra, parse-tree, sql-parser

I need to parse SQL query and form the relational algebra tree. Currently I used the postgres internal parser to parse the query. (More specificly I've the result of step 1 in the link bellow).

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/parser-stage.html

What I'm looking for is the source code or an implementation of the second part, Transformation Process. I searched a little but could not find it.

Also any other recommendations to form the relational algebra tree from the sql query?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the ***debug_print_plan (boolean)*** in logging options to print the execution plan.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-logging.html